# How do you stub all methods of a particular mock instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, stubbing

I have a particular mock that is being handled by a third party. I just want to check that the same mock has been returned back.

However, the third party calls array methods and save methods that my test doesnt really care about. Is there a way to tell my mock that it expects/stub all methods to do with that particular mock instance?

eg.

```
user = mock(User)
user.stub_all
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

More info about the problem:

Test:

```
  it "creating an invitation should return invitation" do
    invitation = mock_model(Invitation)
    invitation.stub(:[]=)
    invitation.stub(:save)
    Invitation.stub(:create).and_return(invitation)
    @user.create_invitation
    @user.create_invitation.should == invitation        
  end
```

Code being tested:

```
 def create_invitation
    invitation = Invitation.create
    self.invitations.push(invitation)
    return invitation
  end
```

I need to mock the following which are not directly related to what I am testing:

```
invitation.stub(:[]=)
invitation.stub(:save)
```

Comment: I don't know much about Ruby on Rails, or even about Ruby. As such, this is one of the most wacky question titles I have ever seen on this site :D

Comment: What do you mean by "third party" ? Are you trying to create a user object and pass it to a library, have it do whatever it wants to it, and then make sure it is returning you the same mock instance?

Comment: yes, you are right, my explanation did not make much sense. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

```
user = mock(User).as_null_object
```

but in general this approach means your objects are too large and your tests aren't granular enough

Comment: i have updated my question, is your answer still valid. How could I improve my test?

Comment: Actually in this case, you can replace that whole method with `@user.invitations.create` and cut down on a whole load of code that you need to test.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this like I did, you might be looking for `stub_everything()` which creates a `stub` that returns `nil` to all method calls. You can still add expectations too!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this accidentally - but the 'blessed' way of doing this (now) is using the `spy` method, which essentially is the same thing as above:

reference: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/a-closer-look-at-test-spies

You don't have to stub out any methods that the class implements already.